# Is it possible to send a List<string> from controller to view as part of a model in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a model which is something like

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<string?> Stage { get; set; } = new List<string?>();
}
```

I want to pass it from my controller to the view, this part I have no problems with doing something like this:

```
public IActionResult EnterBudgetDetails(CreateABudgetPageModel obj)
{
    obj.Stage.Add("Initial");
    obj.Stage.Add("Test1");
    obj.Stage.Add("Test2");

    return View(obj);     
}
```

This works fine and I am able to iterate through the list in the view.

What I am not sure, is how can I put this into the my view so that I am able to update the values and send them back to the controller as part of the model? I am trying below but it isn't working and can't find anything when searching, so not sure if its even possible?

```
@if (Model != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Stage.Count; i++)
    {
         <input type="hidden" asp-for="Stage[i]" value="@Model.Stage[i]" />
    }
}
```

Comment: "it isn't working" what does it mean?  I can see <input type="hidden"

Answer (score 0):

The code below shows list can be updated in the view and sent back to the controller:

```cs
public IActionResult EnterBudgetDetails()
{
    var obj = new MyModel();
    obj.Stage.Add("Initial");
    obj.Stage.Add("Test1");
    obj.Stage.Add("Test2");

    return View(obj);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EnterBudgetDetails(MyModel obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // TODO...
    }

    return View(obj);
}
```

`EnterBudgetDetails.cshtml`:

```
@model Models.MyModel

@if (Model != null)
{
  <form asp-controller="Your_controller" method="post">
      @for (int i=0; i < Model.Stage.Count; i++)
      {
          <div><input type="text" asp-for="Stage[i]" value="@Model.Stage[i]" /></div><br>
      }
      
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </div>
  </form>
}
```